# How to make mathematical comparisons in github action expressions

Tags: github-actions

For a GitHub action workflow, I want to compare two variables in an `if` condition to determine if a step should be run. However, the comparison seems to happen as a string comparison, e.g., 8060 gets evaluated greater than 65536. How can I force these to be a mathematical comparison?

```
jobs:
  generate-report:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Generate update review report
    outputs:
      update-report: ${{ steps.set-update-report.outputs.report }}
      update-report-length: ${{ steps.set-update-report.outputs.length }}
    steps:
      - name: Get depdive update report
        id: set-update-report
        run: |
          output="$(depdive update-review paths ./base/ ./)"
          echo "::set-output name=report::${output}"
          length=$(echo ${output} | wc -c )
          echo "::set-output name=length::${length}"


  make-pr-comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Comment on PR
    needs: generate-report
    env:
      MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS: 65536
    steps:
      - name: make valid comment
        if: ${{ needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report && needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report-length < env.MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS }}
        # expects mathematical comparison here
        run: |
          echo "valid"
      - name: make comment when output too big
        if: ${{ needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report && needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report-length >= env.MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS }}
        # expects mathematical comparison here
        run: |
          echo "invalid"
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar in [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester6.yml) recently and I observed that if expression weren't working using number as outputs ou as env variable for comparison. I could only make it work using directly number values (here is the whole [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/3050190940?check_suite_focus=true)). Let me know if you find a way to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

The "[Context and expression syntax for GitHub Actions / Operator](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators)" documentation states:

> If the types do not match, GitHub coerces the type to a number.

You can use the [`fromJSON` function](https://%20https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) to force the comparison as numbers. The `fromJSON` function tries to parse the input as a JSON value and, if successful, returns the corresponding value.
Since numbers are valid JSON values, you can use this function to ensure a numerical comparison.

That would be, for your workflow with the `fromJSON` function:

```yaml
jobs:
  generate-report:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Generate update review report
    outputs:
      update-report: ${{ steps.set-update-report.outputs.report }}
      update-report-length: ${{ steps.set-update-report.outputs.length }}
    steps:
      - name: Get depdive update report
        id: set-update-report
        run: |
          output="$(depdive update-review paths ./base/ ./)"
          echo "::set-output name=report::${output}"
          length=$(echo ${output} | wc -c )
          echo "::set-output name=length::${length}"


  make-pr-comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Comment on PR
    needs: generate-report
    env:
      MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS: 65536
    steps:
      - name: make valid comment
        if: ${{ needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report && fromJSON(needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report-length) < fromJSON(env.MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS) }}
        # expects mathematical comparison here
        run: |
          echo "valid"
      - name: make comment when output too big
        if: ${{ needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report && fromJSON(needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report-length) >= fromJSON(env.MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS) }}
        # expects mathematical comparison here
        run: |
          echo "invalid"
```

That includes: `${{ needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report && fromJSON(needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report-length) < fromJSON(env.MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS) }}`

Now, the comparison between `needs.generate-report.outputs.update-report-length` and `env.MAX_ALLOWED_CHARS` will be treated as numerical, and the expected behavior should work as intended.

Comment: are you sure `+` is valid within gha expression? I get an error otherwise

Comment: I thought it was an operator, but it is not. The goal is to somehow concatenate a .0 in order to force the values to be considered as int.